# how can i change the wordpress theme's url, after change the site url

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have installed a theme on 'http://ip' successfully，then i change the site to 'http://example.com',but the domain.com still access ip's theme,i just [Changing_The_Site_URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

my site is http://yimi.us/ and with F12 in chrome can display unaccessable url how can i resolve it.

Comment: I checked your site then i found 3 things are coming from Ip website.I think you need to change that the logo path then issue will solve

Comment: thanks a lot.i just added the logo.

Comment: Is its working for you??

Comment: yes it work fine.maybe just now is cache.

Comment: Works fine. Just clear you browser history and cache